# Why can only one UDP client running on same host receive messages?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, udp

I've written two C++ programs running on Ubuntu - one is a UDP client program and the other is a UDP server program.  The server program sends a UDP multicast packet every 5 seconds.  The client program(s), receives the server packet and responds.  The client program has a simple loop and uses recvfrom() function to read the data (synchronously) and then uses sendto() to respond to the server.

I'm running the client (A) and the server programs on the same host and everything works well.  The issue that I'm having is when I start a second instance of the client program B on the same host, then client A stops receiving data and only client B receives data.  If I stop client A and restart it then client A will get the data but client B stops receiving data.  I'm already using setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) in my client which is why I'm able to run multiple instances of my client.

How can I make it so multiple instances of the client program can receive data simultaneously?

Comment: [multicasting](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-2.html) springs to mind. Regardless, a simple [mcve] of both server and client to make sure you're not doing something wrong would probably go a long way for your post.

Comment: Am assuming both clients on the same port:  the 1st client receives the data; it's gone from the network stack, so there is no data to be received for client 2.  If this wasn't the case then the network stack would clog up with packets.

Comment: If you want, I'll right up a longer answer about RX queues and whatnot.  But the bottom line is this: each incoming datagram gets delivered to exactly 1 socket.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure for your scenario that if client B got busy after doing a `recvfrom`, client A would get the next packet if client B didn't come back to block on `recvfrom` again.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you expected this to work. Which client did you want to receive the data? How would the computer know which client you wanted to receive the data? Or were you expecting the data to be cloned to each listening socket? Did the sockets set up successfully? Are you sure? Did you verify that? Too many details missing here to answer.

Comment: Yes, both clients are on the same port - 5000 - which is also the port the server is sending on.  I expected all client processes running on the same host to get the same message that is sent by the server since it is multicast.  But as a few of you pointed out, since the client processes are running on the same host, only one process will be able to read the data from the socket.  After that, there is no data packet left for the other process to read.

Comment: It is interesting though that the last process to bind to the port will start receiving the messages and the other client processes will stop receiving them.  I assume, the kernal/tcp stack will only deliver to one process in a last-come-first-serve basis.

Comment: In my experience multicast packets do get delivered to multiple clients on the same host (if those clients are all bound to the same UDP port and are members of the multicast group, of course).  Dunno why that isn't happening for you.

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is more or less what I would expect if you *weren't* using ip multicast.  Multiple clients on the same host can bind to the same port (because the SO_REUSEADDR sockopt is specified) but the network layer only passes the datagram to one of the clients -- typically the last one bound to the port.  What ip address are you using?